# Swift: Trying to retrieve the data from a dataSource Struct

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, completionhandler

Here is my code below:

```
class DataSource: NSObject {
    var categories = [String]()
    var items = [Item]()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    class var sharedDataSource: DataSource {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: DataSource!
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            let dataSource = DataSource()
            Static.instance = dataSource

            let urlPath = "myUrlPathString"
            let endpoint = NSURL(string: urlPath)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: endpoint!)

            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request,completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                let json = JSON(data: data!)
                print(json)
                for obj in json.arrayValue {
                    let item: Item = Item()
                    item.itemID = obj["item"].stringValue
                    item.price = obj["price"].floatValue
                    item.title = obj["title"].stringValue
                    item.category = obj["category"].stringValue
                    item.available = obj["available"].boolValue
                    item.image = obj["image"].stringValue
                    print(item.title)
                    dataSource.items.append(item)
                    print(dataSource.items)
                    print("STOP")
                }
            }).resume()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the result of this dataSource in a UICollectionView, by assigning its result to an Item array.  I am successfully grabbing the data in my NSURLSession, and its local list, 'items', is being populated.

In my UICollectionView, in my viewDidLoad, I am assigning my local variable as follows:

```
let dataSource = DataSource()
items = dataSource.sharedInstance.items
```

Printing the value within the viewDidLoad always results in an empty array with no values, but I know the values are there by the time NURLSession is finished.  I'm not sure how to write a completionhandler for this.  This is my first time doing this kind of thing with a sharedDataSource that is a struct.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in viewDidLoad then it's likely the NSURL session has not completed by the time you try to get your items array. Send a notification in your dataSource class after the data has been received and then set items.

Eg

```
 NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request,completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            let json = JSON(data: data!)
            print(json)
            for obj in json.arrayValue {
                let item: Item = Item()
                item.itemID = obj["item"].stringValue
                item.price = obj["price"].floatValue
                item.title = obj["title"].stringValue
                item.category = obj["category"].stringValue
                item.available = obj["available"].boolValue
                item.image = obj["image"].stringValue
                print(item.title)
                dataSource.items.append(item)
                print(dataSource.items)
                print("STOP")
            }
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("dataRecievedNotification", object: nil)

        }).resume()
```

But you also need to be able to receive this notification in your ViewController with the collectionView. So in viewDidLoad add

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "dataRecieved", name: "dataRecievedNotification", object: nil)
```

Then add a function in the same ViewController:

```
func dataRecieved() {
    print("data received")
    items = dataSource.sharedInstance.items
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Where dataSource is a variable declared above viewDidLoad:

```
let dataSource = DataSource()
```

Don't forget that if you are using observers you need to remove them when the class is removed from memory, so in the ViewController add this deinit function:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

EDIT: I think your singleton pattern can be simplified using modern swift. You don't have to use a struct or dispatch_once any more, just declaring a static let shared instance will handle all that for you. with that in mind, I tried to simplify your dataSource class:

```
class DataSource {

static let sharedInstance = DataSource()

var items = [Item]()

private init() {}

func retrieveItems() {

    let urlPath = "myUrlPathString"
    let endpoint = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: endpoint!)

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request,completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        let json = JSON(data: data!)
        print(json)

        for obj in json.arrayValue {
            let item: Item = Item()
            item.itemID = obj["item"].stringValue
            item.price = obj["price"].floatValue
            item.title = obj["title"].stringValue
            item.category = obj["category"].stringValue
            item.available = obj["available"].boolValue
            item.image = obj["image"].stringValue
            print(item.title)
            items.append(item)
            print(items)
            print("STOP")
        }

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("dataRecievedNotification", object: nil)

    }).resume()

}

}
```

where you, in viewDidLoad, add the following logic:

```
if DataSource.sharedInstance.items.count == 0 {
    DataSource.sharedInstance.retrieveItems()
}
```

then change dataRecieved to

```
func dataRecieved() {
    print("data received")
    items = DataSource.sharedInstance.items //Notice the capital
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

and delete your declaration of var dataSource = DataSource() above viewDidLoad

Comment: I tried out the code above.  Everything appears to be happening in the correct order, but my array is still empty once NSURL Session has finished, and dataReceived is triggered to be executed, items is still an empty array in my UICollectionView for some reason.  Hrm.  I also cannot do:

    let dataSource = DataSource()

Unless I set the initializer to public.  But then, items = dataSource.sharedInstaince.items will not work.  It would have to be items = dataSource.items, and that doesn't trigger the NSURLSession at all. :(

Hrm.

Comment: I changed your dataSource class, please message me if it doesn't make sense/still isn't working :)